# Issue with infinite loop when reading from file

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

I am writing a program in C# to read from a file and output to a csv file all of the unique words and the number of occurrences in the file for each word. My issue is when I try to run my program, I never get out of my while loop that goes line by line.

```
public override List<WordEntry> GetWordCount()
{
        List<WordEntry> words = new List<WordEntry>();
        WordEntry wordEntry = new WordEntry();
        //string[] tokens = null;
        string line, temp, getword;
        int count = 0, index = 0;
        long number;

        while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line == null)
                Debug.Write("shouldnt happen");
            char[] delimit = { ' ', ',' };
            string[] tokens = line.Split(delimit);

            if (words.Count == 0)
            {
                wordEntry.Word = tokens[0];
                wordEntry.WordCount = 1;
                words.Add(wordEntry);
            }//end if

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < words.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (tokens[i] == words[j].Word)
                    {
                        number = words[j].WordCount;
                        number++;
                        getword = words[j].Word;
                        wordEntry.WordCount = number;
                        wordEntry.Word = getword;
                        words.RemoveAt(j);
                        words.Insert(j, wordEntry);
                    }//end if
                    else
                    {
                        wordEntry.Word = tokens[i];
                        wordEntry.WordCount = 1;
                        words.Add(wordEntry);
                    }//end else
                }//end for
            }//end for
        }//end while
        return words;
}
```

It is getting stuck in the while loop as if it never reaches the end of the file. The file is 2.6 MB so it should be able to make it to the end.

Comment: How long did you wait? Thats an awfully large file...

Comment: @BradleyDonNET Yeah I took that into consideration. I waited a good amount of time. I can try again and wait 10 minutes to see if it eventually catches up. I just don't feel like it should take so long.

Comment: Instead of your `List<WordEntry>` why not use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to  quickly check if you have already seen the word instead of looping through all the words you've already seen.

Comment: I don't think you want to use the same `wordEntry` instance in every `for` loop. Since it is a reference type, you are always modifying the WordEntry you added in the previous loop (which is also the one you added in the previous-previous loop, etc.).

Comment: where are you setting the `input` variable - i mean your input file?

Comment: What is `input`? Is it a `StreamReader`?

Comment: I opt this doesn't end just because of the terrible performance, you get a square complexity because each word is compared to the list of previous words. Instead, use a dictionary, that would make the scan linear.

Comment: @Otiel you're right, that means the number of entries in the `words` list increases by 1 for each loop, unless there are identical words back to back.

Comment: @CrApHeR Yes it is a StreamReader. Sorry about that.

Comment: Firstly, you should skip searching through words for the first iteration when you're adding the initial one. Secondly, you should only resort to adding to words after you've completely searching through ALL of them without finding the token. Also, using Dictionary<string, int> instead could greatly simplify the implementation.

Comment: The code in this question is a good example, why one function should only do 1 thing. The function here tries to do 2 things: Read the lines and process them. So the author of the question thinks, his readline() related code fails (and his debugger seems broken...), while it is the processing code which causes the problem. It would be as easy for you as commenting 1 line of code to see how long your reading while loop takes if there is no processing if you had your processing in a subroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can rewrite your code to use a dictionary.

```
var words = new Dictionary<string,int>();

while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line == null)
        Debug.Write("shouldnt happen");
    char[] delimit = { ' ', ',' };
    string[] tokens = line.Split(delimit);

    foreach (var word in tokens)
    {
        if(words.ContainsKey(word))
            words[word]++;
        else
            words.Add(word, 1);
    }
}
```

This reduces the complexity of the code because dictionary has a O(1) lookup.

**EDIT**

You can convert the dictionary into `List<WordEntry>` like this.

```
return words
    .Select(kvp => new WorkEntry
        {
            Word = kvp.Key, 
            WordCount = kvp.Value
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Looking good. I think you can skip the call to words.ContainsKey and just use te indexer straight to always ++

Comment: @juharr I will look into this. I appreciate your help. My only problem with looking at this is this is a prewritten method that I am required to write the beef for. It must return a List<>. Is this possible without breaking up the Dictionary into two different Lists?

Comment: return words.Keys.ToList()

Comment: @Biscuits Beautiful. I will give this a shot and get back to you.

Comment: @Biscuits How would I get that in a format that can be returned as a List<WordEntry>? It has to return in such a way that the List contains both the word and the count for the word and I am not sure how to get this Dictionary to the correct format to return.

Comment: return words.Select(p => new WordEntry { Word = p.Key, WordCount = p.Value }).ToList()

Comment: @Biscuits Doesn't that just create a whole new WordEntry so that I would only return 1 word and its count?

Comment: No, the list could have more than one WordEntry element - exactly one for every unique key (word) from the dictionary. Select will enumerate through each KeyValuePair (word) from the dictionary.

Comment: @Biscuits The call to `ContainsKey` is required because a dictionary will throw an exception if you try to get the indexer with a key that it does not contain.

Comment: @juharr That's right. But I'm proposing that we only call the setter (and not any getter). The setter is already smart enough to "add-if-not-exists-else-update"... :)

Comment: @Biscuits You have to remember that `i++` is the same as `i = i + 1`, so when you do `words[word]++` you are calling the getter and then the setter.

Comment: @juharr Sorry, my mistake. I overlooked that very important fact.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in fact your code doesn't get out of the "for (int j = 0; j < words.Count; j++)" because new items are kept being added to the words list.